# Focal Length from Monocular Calibration

Tags: calibration, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wondering if the parameters saved from running the cameracalibrator.py node contain the focal length/s of the camera somewhere inside. If not, is it possible to determine a focal length based on these values?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12498/focal-length-from-monocular-calibration/) by [jamesp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1596/jamesp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-01-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The camera matrix, as written out by cameracalibrator.py is as follows:

```
Fx  0  Cx
0   Fy Cy
0   0   1
```

where Fx and Fy are the x and y focal lengths in pixels, and (Cx, Cy) is the principal point.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jamesp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1596/jamesp/) on 2012-01-08**:
Thank you for your reply!

**Comment by [zubair](https://answers.ros.org/users/29938/zubair/) on 2018-12-27**:
hi, but these Fx and Fy can be found from camera parameters (intrinsic), but what is the actual focal length of the camera ? in formula Fx = f * Mx , where Mx is pixel/mm on image sensor. how can we get that !! any idea !